# How to merge records from two tables into third using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables A, B, C

Schema of all 3 tables is same as mentioned below:

1st A table:

```
cpid ,name, place
```

2nd B table:

```
connectorid,dob
```

3rd C table:

```
ccpid cconnectorid
```

Now both tables A and B have many records.
Now some of the records in A and B are with same id.
Now I want to merge the records from A and B into Table C.
Merge logic is as follows

```
1)If records with cpid = connectorid ,insert into table c.
2)C Table  ccpid is the foreignkey for A table cpid and cconnectorid is the foreignkey B table connectorid.
3)Using select query.
```

Comment: why are you intending to keep duplicate columns in `C` table (`ccpid cconnectorid`)? And what does the `ccity`  column refer to?

Comment: what you have tried so far? we are not here to work for you..

Comment: why you need two columns in C table (ccpid cconnectorid) because u save same values in both column. Above you mention `cpid = connectorid`???

Answer (score 1):

You can use select insert  with a n inner join

```
 insert into table_c
 select a.cpid, b.connectorid, a.place
 from table_b as b
 inner join table_a as a  on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: you forgot to put comma

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution for your query:

```
INSERT INTO `C`(`ccpid`, `cconnectorid`, `ccity`)
SELECT ta.`cpid`, ta.`cconnectorid`, tb.`place`
FROM `A`  as ta
  INNER JOIN `B` tb ON ta.`cpid` = tb.`cconnectorid`
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need join data from both tables? This is simple JOIN function.

```
SELECT *
    FROM Table_A
    INNER JOIN Table_B
    ON Table_A.cpid =Table_B.connectorid;
```

You can insert this select to your Table_C.

Here is INNER JOIN, but I think you should take a look to JOINs, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) are examples and you can read more about other JOINs.

> **INNER JOIN**: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH
>   tables **LEFT JOIN**: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched
>   rows from the right table  **RIGHT JOIN**: Return all rows from the right
>   table, and the matched rows from the left table  **FULL JOIN**: Return all
>   rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables

Answer (score 0):

use following query replace with your table names

```
INSERT INTO CTABLE(ccpid,cconnectorid,ccity)
(SELECT A.cpid ,B.connectorid, A.place FROM 
TABLEA A INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.cpid = B.connectorid)
```